# Change button background image, text and shape on hover at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I am wondering if it is possible to make a button background image or text change to another text or image along with the button shape on mouse hover?

Say I had a button having a certain text or background image shoving the symbol ✓ (checkmark) and I wish it to change shape (from a circle to a rectangle) and text (from checkmark to the word *submit*) on mouse hover.

Is it possible using CSS, JS or both?

Comment: Yes it is possible with both CSS and JS, separately and both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Without Changing Animations

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgta5f1b/)

If you just want to change the background image and shape, you can use pure CSS

```
.button {
    height:30px;
    width:60px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-image:url(...)
}
.button:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    background-image:url(...)
}
```

If you want to change the text, you need JavaScript.

```
<style>
    #button {
        height:30px;
        width:60px;
        border-radius:15px;
        background-image:url(img1.png);
    }
</style>
<script>
    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundImage = "url(img2.png)";
        document.getElementById("button").style.borderRadius = "0px";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Submit";
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementById("button").style.backgroundImage = "url(img1.png)";
        document.getElementById("button").style.borderRadius = "15px";
        document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "✓";
    }
</script>

<div id="button" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">✓</div>
```

---

### With Changing Animations

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbsdtctL/)
To animate the button, use the

```
-webkit-transition:all 0.2s;
transition:all 0.2s;
```

functions. Every property that is changed in the :hover css, is automatically animated with a duration of 0.2 seconds.
If you also want the text to change (in my example fading in and out) it gets a little more complicated. (Disclaimer: My solution is probably not the most elegant one, but it works.)

Add two more classes to your CSS, *.fade-out* and *.fade-in*.

```
.fade-out {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeOut 0.2s;
}
.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
}
```

*In this case I wanted the text animation to be a little longer than the border animation (I think it looks better), but if they should be the same length, you have to set each of the animations to 0.1s*

Then add two *@keyframes* animations, *fadeOut* and *fadeIn* like this:

```
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Now the tricky part, the JavaScript:

```
function mouseIsOver() {  
    btn = document.getElementById("button_java");
    btn.childNodes[0].className += ' fade-out';
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "Submit";
        btn.childNodes[0].className = btn.childNodes[0].className.replace(' fade-out', '');
        btn.childNodes[0].className += ' fade-in';
        setTimeout(function(){
            btn.childNodes[0].className = btn.childNodes[0].className.replace(' fade-in', '');
        }, 200);
    }, 200);
}

function mouseIsOut() {
    btn = document.getElementById("button_java");
    btn.childNodes[0].className += ' fade-out';
    setTimeout(function(){
        btn.childNodes[0].innerHTML = "✓";
        btn.childNodes[0].className = btn.childNodes[0].className.replace(' fade-out', '');
        btn.childNodes[0].className += ' fade-in';
        setTimeout(function(){
            btn.childNodes[0].className = btn.childNodes[0].className.replace(' fade-in', '');
        }, 200);
    }, 200);
}
```

- **childNodes[0]** gets all inner children (tags), and chooses the first one
- **className += ' fade-out'** adds the class '*fade-out*' to the elements class list. There needs to be a **space** in front of the added class name, just so if there are classes already defined, they won't combine into one non-existent class
- **setTimeout(*function*,*waitduration*)** runs the code in *function* after it waitet *waitduration* milliseconds. Match this length to the duration of your animation in the `.fade-out{...}` class in your CSS-file
- **className.replace(' fade-out','')** replaces the *fade-out* class in the elements list of classes with an empty string to remove it. Don't forget to remove the space, too.

---

### Your Personalized Button

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa3dcs3k/2/) or [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/Rr4sq2TP)
I've copied the code from your page, added a `<p>` wrap around the text in the button, and added

```
.button p {
    line-height:1em;
    margin:0;
}
```

to the CSS.
Then you need to import jQuery by adding

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
```

into the head. Then add another code snippet,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#subscribe_button").hover(
                function() {
                txt = $("#subscribe_button").children("p");
                txt.fadeOut(100, function() {
                        txt.html("Sottoscrivi");
                        txt.fadeIn();
                });
          }, function() {
                txt = $("#subscribe_button").children("p");
                txt.stop(true,false).fadeOut(100, function() {
                        txt.html("✓");
                        txt.fadeIn();
                });
          }
        );
});
</script>
```

That should be it!

Comment: That's great! What about having the change less abrupt, for instance as a CSS transition, therefore with a given timing and not that snappy?

Comment: Thanks soo much! You left me a tough nut to crack here. All that is way beyond my capabilities, but I will parse it carefully. [Here](http://www.ilcontadinobio.it/tests/index.html) a yet clearly incomplete button version (just to give you an idea of how the animation has to be - the button is supposed to be round with the checkmark symbol/image and then elongate, on mouse hover, to accommodate the writing _submit_). If you feel comfortable with writing even the part where the text change it will be enormously appreciated.

Comment: So, on the green button under the newsletter section (Captioned _Sottoscrivi_) you want to display a check mark in a circular button and when they hover over it, the button becomes wider and the text changes to _Sottoscrivi_? Is that correct, or is there another button on your webpage that I am not aware of?

Comment: And additionally, would you be willing to add the jQuery library? Because that would make it a whole lot easier.

Comment: I've not waited for your answer and just used jQuery, so see the edited answer above for the code!
And if that helped, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Yeah, you earned it. 
One last request: is it possible to override the transition delay on mouse-click, make whatever changes happen sharply?

Comment: @dRyW [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa3dcs3k/1/) I have moved the transition styles to it's own class, and added this class to the button. Then I added some jQuery Javascript .mousedown() and .mouseup() to remove and readd the transition class to the button.
I also realized, that you repeat the same gradient css in the :hover class from your normal .button class, which is unneccessary.

Comment: Half of what I do is unnecessary. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Hi, I already have several jQuery library calls in my page which conflicts have been solved (unfortunately I've no idea how) with the aid of another forum. Indeed `jquery-2.1.3.js` call clashes whit one of them (the image slider). Do you believe you may solve it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but it seems to work on your page. I thing just importing the jQuery version your image slider nheeds, should be fine, since the functions aren't all that new. (If that's what your question was)

Comment: Well I'm no idea what version the slider needs but I suppose it is the one currently loaded, It's curious though, if I place `jquery-2.1.3.js` call before the image slider's ones, the slider works otherwise it doesn't. In both cases however text animation and `removeclass()` on muosedown don't work. You can check it by yourself [here](http://www.ilcontadinobio.it/tests/index.html)

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the script code I provided you with? Because I can't find it on your page. Or where did you put it?

Comment: If you mean the snippet of js code it is right after the calls in the head (from line 26). The css is just after the button `div` (line 415). Were there else?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell you that in the Fiddle it executes _onLoad_, so when it is not in the fiddle you need to wrap the javascript in `$( document ).ready(function() { /* Code here */ });`

Comment: Oh yeah, working now! I was wondering how to delay "✓" in order to be visible enough time (in our case 500ms) for the CSS transition to confer it colour before the `fadeout`. I was thinking about some event within the method `.hover` but I'm still too inexperienced for that - I've just begun reading about `js` and you've given me something to play with. The question, however, as far as I ( and you) might be concerned has been answered, so if you are to busy to pay attention to this it's going to be alright.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to keep the "✓" until the CSS animation is done?

Comment: Exactly, to make "✓" changing colour (because of the CSS transition) and then changing in another text (with js). Right now it disappears along with the transition. I tried to change the `fadeout` timing but no matter the value it starts fading as soon as the cursor triggers the `.hover` you'd have to delay/override the `fadeout` itself a value <= the CSS transition, I think.